# Do inviscid fluids have thermal conductivity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, viscosity, superfluidity, heat-conduction

Inviscid fluids are an idealization and they don't have viscosity. The no-slip boundary condition DOESN'T apply to them and consequently, these fluids won't display a hydrodynamic boundary layer.
I've been thinking about the thermal effects of an inviscid fluid flow. Would we have conductivity? Would we have a thermal boundary layer? Can anyone explain that?

Comment: If I remember correctly, both viscosity and heat conductivity terms spring from the same higher-than-2nd order perturbation in the kinetic theory derivation of fluid dynamics. So neglecting viscosity, one would have to also neglect conductivity, for consistencies sake.

Comment: Sure there would be a thermal boundary layer and heat conduction in an inviscid fluid.